# FltGetStreamHandleContext And FltSetStreamHandleContext Function

Tags: api, filter, driver

Is the structure of the third parameter of FltGetStreamHandleContext a user-defined structure? And before you get the Context via FltGetStreamHandleContext, do you have to predefine the Context through the FltSetStreamHandleContext function? Sorry for the inconvenience of using the translator.

Answer (score 0):

yes, to what is point `PFLT_CONTEXT` is *user-defined structure* - so you yourself design it content. you need allocate it by call [`FltAllocateContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541710(v=vs.85).aspx). really this function allocate more then *ContextSize* parameter for hold reference count on allocated context (initially it equal 1) and [`FSRTL_PER_STREAM_CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547357(v=vs.85).aspx) because `FltSetStream[Handle]Context` shell over [`FsRtlInsertPerStreamContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546194(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`FsRtlInsertPerFileObjectContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546189(v=vs.85).aspx) (*read more [Tracking Per-Stream Context in a Legacy File System Filter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/tracking-per-stream-context-in-a-legacy-file-system-filter-driver)*)

if you not call `FltSetStream[Handle]Context` before `FltGetStream[Handle]Context` - you got `NULL_CONTEXT` (or simply 0) (more exactly `FltGetStream[Handle]Context` return error `STATUS_NOT_FOUND`)

so again context is your defined structure in mini-filter drivers (in legacy you need inherit context from [`FSRTL_PER_STREAM_CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547357(v=vs.85).aspx) but minifiletrs encapsulate this)

usually we use next code;

```
MY_STREAM_CONTEXT* Ctx;// your custom data
if (0 <= FltGetStreamHandleContext(FltObjects->Instance, FltObjects->FileObject, (PFLT_CONTEXT*)&Ctx))
{
  //.. use Ctx
  FltReleaseContext(Ctx);
}
```